# Handling exceptions in guard blocks

Tags: swift, exception

I'm looking for an elegant way of combining `guard` blocks with `do-try-catch` semantics in Swift, and haven't been satisfied with my own efforts so far.

For background, I'm getting hold of some necessary data from a function that throws an exception *and* can return an Optional value.  As a concrete example, let's say I'm looking up the most recent item from a TODO list stored on the filesystem.  This can legitimately be `nil` (nothing on the list), or it can thrown an exception (some sort of I/O error accessing the filesystem), so both cases are distinct.

For the rest of the method though, we only care if there is a item to operate on - so this sounds like an ideal case for `guard`:

```
func myCoolMethod() {
    guard let todoItem = try? fetchItemFromList() else {
        // No item to act on, nothing to do
        return
    }

    // rest of function acts on todoItem
    ...
}
```

This is indeed fine - **until** the guard block starts failing when you expect it to succeed, and you'd really like to (if nothing else) log the error message to try and investigate.  As such, the `try?` needs to be replaced by a `try` to allow the error to be captured, and now we'll need to wrap the `guard` in a `do` block:

```
func myCoolMethod() {
    do {
        guard let todoItem = try fetchItemFromList() else {
            // No item to act on, nothing to do
            return
        }

        // rest of function acts on todoItem
        ...
    }
    catch {
        // Now we know there was an error of some sort (can specialize the
        // catch block if we need to be more precise)

        // log error or similar, then...
        return
    }
}
```

There are two problems with this that I see:

1. The `do` block needs to wrap the whole method (due to the scope of `todoItem`).  This means that the happy-path logic is indented (which is something that `guard` specifically helps to avoid); but additionally, it means that any errors from that logic will be caught by the `catch` block, perhaps accidentally.  I'd much prefer the `do` block to only be scoped around the `guard`.
2. There's duplication of the "what to do if we have no item" block.  In this trivial example it's just a `return`, but it still pains me a little to have two separate blocks that need to do broadly the same thing (where one just adds a little extra context with the error being available).

I'd like to get as close to this as possible:

```
func myCoolMethod() {
    // `do guard` is made up but would enter the else block either if an exception
    // is thrown, or the pattern match/conditional fails
    do guard let todoItem = try fetchItemFromList() else {
        if let error = error {
            // Optional `error` is only bound if the guard failed due to an exception
            // here we can log it etc.
        }

        // This part is common for both the case where an exception was thrown,
        // and the case where the method successfully returned `nil`, so we can
        // implement the common logic for handling "nothing to act on"
        return
    }

    // rest of function acts on todoItem
    ...
}
```

What are my options here?

Answer (score 2):

First, look for errors and deal with them. Then look for existence, and deal with that:

```
func myCoolMethod() {
    // Making this `let` to be stricter. `var` would remove need for `= nil` later
    let todoItem: Item?

    // First check for errors
    do {
        todoItem = try fetchItemFromList()
    } catch {
        todoItem = nil  // Need to set this in either case
        // Error handling
    }

    // And then check for values
    guard let todoItem = todoItem else {
        // No item to act on (missing or error), nothing to do
        return
    }

    // rest of function acts on todoItem
    print(todoItem)
}
```

Or separate the problems into functions. When things get complicated, make more focused functions:

```
func myCoolMethod() {
    // And then check for values
    guard let todoItem = fetchItemAndHandleErrors() else {
        // No item to act on (missing or error), nothing to do
        return
    }

    // rest of function acts on todoItem
    print(todoItem)
}

func fetchItemAndHandleErrors() -> Item? {
    // First check for errors
    do {
        return try fetchItemFromList()
    } catch {
        // Error handling
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: The first code block does not compile, the second declaration of `todoItem` conflicts with the first one. Did you mean to use different variable names?

Comment: @MartinR Strange, it compiles for me. `todoItem` intentionally shadows the first one. What error did you get?

Comment: "Definition conflicts with previous value" on the `guard let todoItem = ...` line.

Comment: @MartinR that's weird. Here's my gist that I use in a commandline app. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/6f14610ce1897f538feaaf779ab90878   I know there was a "in its own definition" bug fix that was just added in 12.5 beta 3 (which I'm using), but I thought it only applied to functions and properties.

Comment: That would explain it, I am using 12.4 right now.